# CSS scale transform with transition ignores clip-path

Tags: css, transform, scale, transition, clip-path

While the `transfom` takes place, the `clip-path` seems to be ignored:

```js
var zoom = false;

setInterval(function(){

  if(zoom == false) {
    zoom = true;
    $('.circle').attr('class','circle zoom');
  }
  else {
    $('.circle').attr('class','circle');
    zoom = false;
  }   
},1000);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(120px at center);
  clip-path: circle(120px at center);
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.circle{
  display:block;
  
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300" alt="" class="circle">
</div>
```

Does anybody know why this is, and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Place clip-path to class circle, not to wrapper.

```js
var zoom = false;

setInterval(function(){

  if(zoom == false) {
    zoom = true;
    $('.circle').addClass('zoom');
  }
  else {
    $('.circle').removeClass('zoom');
    zoom = false;
  }   
},1000);
```

```css
.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.circle{
  display:block;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(120px at center);
  clip-path: circle(120px at center);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="//placehold.it/300" alt="" class="circle">
```

Comment: But this scales the clip-path as well, which I do not want to happen.